# package android.support.v4.app does not exist ; in Android studio 0.8

Tags: java, sdk, ide, android-studio, android-support-library

I've recently updated the android studio IDE to 0.8 to work with the new android L SDK. To start I imported a finished android project that receives no errors in the older version of android studio. In version 0.8 i lines such as

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

get: Support cannot be resolved causing the rest of the code to have errors. The logcat returns 101 instances of

```
Error:(8, 30) error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
```

1 for each time I call the support library in an import statement.

I've tried

- reinstalling the IDE
- deleting contents of idea folder
- re installing all the SDK's - including the support libraries
- syncing the gradle
- copying the support library into the libs folder manually
- rebuilding the project
- as well as creating a new project to test the library

not entirely sure what's left to do.

Comment: Does gradle sync succeed successfully? Is the support library on your dependency list?

Comment: gradle fails, and i added the support to the dependency list

Comment: have you installed the repository from SDK manager?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[for some reasons this answer is related to Eclipse, NOT Android Studio!]**

Have you tried setting the support libraries to your class path? [This link](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) from the Android Developer's website has some info on how to do that.

Try following these steps from the website:

Create a library project based on the support library code:

- Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the SDK Manager.
- Create a library project and ensure the required JAR files are included in the project's build path:

  - Select **File > Import**.
  - Select E**xisting Android Code Into Workspace** and click Next.
  - Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support Library folder. For example, if you are adding the *appcompat* project, browse to /extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/.
  - Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 appcompat project, you should now see a new project titled **android-support-v7-appcompat**.
  - In the new library project, expand the **libs/** folder, right-click each .jar file and select **Build Path > Add to Build Path**. For example, when creating the the v7 appcompat project, add both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files to the build path.
  - Right-click the library project folder and select **Build Path > Configure Build Path**.
  - In the **Order and Export** tab, check the .jar files you just added to the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this library project. For example, the appcompat project requires you to export both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files.
  - Uncheck **Android Dependencies**.
  - Click OK to complete the changes.
- You now have a library project for your selected Support Library that you can use with one or more application projects.

  - Add the library to your application project:
  - In the **Project Explorer**, right-click your project and select **Properties**.
  - In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select **Android**.
  - In the **Library** pane, click the **Add** button.
  - Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be  listed as android-support-v7-appcompat.
  - In the properties window, click OK.

Comment: when i try that i know get Error:Could not find method complie() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@ad93a93.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Answer (score 114):

Ok, so I had the same problem and found a solution in a udacity forum:

In Android Studio:

1. Right click on your projects "app" folder and click on -> module settings
2. Click on the "dependencies" tab
3. Click on the + sign to add a new dependency and select "Library Dependency"
4. Look for the library you need and add it

Comment: Perhaps, didn't work for me, who didn't have an `app` folder after importing from Eclipse. I saw some message about conflicting versions of the support package. Was just copying the newer one over the older one before but I think something got updated.

Comment: it works for me..simple but makes us frustrated if we find the issues

Comment: Worked for me as well. Had to include android.support dependency and now all build errors related to android.support.v4.app package not found have vanished.

Comment: In Android Studio 3.6, there was no "Module Settings" option when right-clicking on the "app" folder, but there was an "Open Module Settings" when right-clicking on the top-level project.  The shortcut key is F4.  However its "Dependencies" tab lists nothing referencing a `support-v4` library.

Answer (score 39):

@boernard 's answer solves this from the Android Studio IDE, but if you want to understand what's happening under the covers, it's a simple gradle build file update:

You can edit the build.gradle file from within the IDE (left pane: `Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle (Module: app)`) or use the raw path (`<proj_dir>/app/build.gradle`)
and add/update the following dependency section:

```
dependencies {
    //
    // IDE setting pulls in the specific version of v4 support you have installed:
    //
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'

    //
    // generic directive pulls in any available version of v4 support:
    //
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

Using the above *generic* compile directive, allows you to ship your code to anyone, provided they have some level of the `Android Support Libraries v4` installed.

Comment: Great I did the same...and works for me... I added to the gradle compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'

Answer (score 38):

None of the above solutions worked for me. What finally worked was:

Instead of

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
```

Use this

```
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
```

This path is updated as of AndroidX (the repackaged Android Support Library).

Comment: Thank you! this led me to also import ContextCompat!

Answer (score 11):

Delete

```
/.idea/libraries
```

Then sync gradle to build project.

Comment: This was the fix for me. The dependency had previously been correctly set up in gradle, but a Kotlin plugin version update *broke everything*, and the fix was to remove `.idea/libraries`, then `Invalidate Caches/Restart` in Android Studio.

Comment: This did not work for me but helped me towards a solution because all the files I was expecting to be the folder did not get re-created.

Answer (score 5):

// run this commend - its fixed everything

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter

Answer (score 4):

In my case the error was on a module of my project.I have resolved this with adding

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
}
```

this dependency in gradle of corresponding module

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Remove all unused modules which have a dependency on the support library from your `settings.gradle`.

*Long version:*

In our case we had declared the support library as a dependency for all of our modules (one app module and multiple library modules) in a `common.gradle` file which is imported by every module. However there was one library module which wasn't declared as a dependency for any other module and therefore wasn't build. In every few syncs Android Studio would pick that exact module as the one where to look for the support library (that's why it appeared to happen randomly for us). As this module was never used it never got build which in turn caused the jar file not being in the intermediates folder of the module.

Removing this library module from `settings.gradle` and syncing again fixed the problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

IN ECLIPSE LUNA 
I ve resolved this issue by using contet menu on my Project : ANdroid Tools > Add support Library ...

Answer (score 1):

If none of these solution worked, you need to jetify your project to fully support AndroidX. Try

`npm i -D jetifier`

then run

`npx jetify`

you could find more details here : https://github.com/michalchudziak/react-native-geolocation/issues/39#issuecomment-514566895 ,this should fix the issues. Let me know if this worked.

and also make sure to add below  in gradle.properties

`android.useAndroidX=true`

`android.enableJetifier=true`

Comment: this worked. But why ?

Comment: React Native apps are not standard Android apps. React Native modules with native Java code usually distribute that code as source, and link the source code directly. When you update your modules, the freshly installed Java code from your react-native dependencies will not be translated to AndroidX anymore, and your build will fail. So you have to perform an AndroidX migration on your linked source every time you update react native modules that ship native Java code. That is what this tool does - it can rewrite the source in node_modules every time you call it. 
     Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! yes that is quite insightful.

Answer (score 1):

**March 9th 2023**

If you're using Ionic/Angular, this worked for me:

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
npx jetify
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was solved by appending the string `cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:+` to `platforms/android/project.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was caused by a gradle.properties file in the list of Gradle scripts. It showed as gradle.properties (global) and refered to a file in C:\users\.gradle\gradle.properties. I right-clicked on it and selected delete from the menu to delete it. It deleted the file from the hard disk and my project now builds and runs. I guess that the global file was overwriting something that was used to locate the package android.support

Answer (score 0):

My solution was creating a project with `Use legacy support library` option `checked`. after the project creation is successfully completed, just `delete` the `src` folder in the app directory and `copy` the `src` folder from your main project. Finally, `Sync` project with Gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
}
```

*Must have minSdkVersion 14 (or higher)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION TO
error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

using jetify helped to solve .

from @ jcesarmobile' s post --- >#2832

Error: "package android.support.* does not exist"
This error occurs when some Cordova or Capacitor plugin has old android support dependencies instead of using the new AndroidX equivalent.
You should report the issue in the plugin repository so the maintainers can update the plugin to use AndroidX dependencies.

As workaround you can also patch the plugin using jetifier

npm install jetifier

npx jetify

npx cap sync android