# Tried everything but the right thing: Android SDK, Import Unknown

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I'm building an Android app (I'm totally new to all this), and I've hit an error I haven't been able to get around.

error:
      package android.support.v4.view does not exist

I've tried looking for it in the SDK Manager, and I've installed all of the packages that have "support" in the name. 
Can any of you point me in the right direction here? 
I'm working off of the thenewboston Android App Development tutorials.

Thanks so much

Comment: see belows links they might help you ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545576/how-to-fix-error-package-android-support-v4-app-does-not-exist-in-android-stu
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update/16610247#16610247
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570

Comment: [This might help you reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545576/how-to-fix-error-package-android-support-v4-app-does-not-exist-in-android-stu/)