# Qt - package android.support.v4.app does not exist

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I'm using Qt 5.4. I imported SDK & NDK.

[image]

Actually, I was trying to use multiple line notification and I used this line in java file:

**customMainActivity.java:**

```
   import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        context);
```

I'm getting an error :
***package android.support.v4.app does not exist*** 
I read [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545576/package-android-support-v4-app-does-not-exist-in-android-studio-0-8) and [it](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.android/6510) and added *android-support-v4.jar* and *android-support-v7-appcompat.jar* but I don't know how to fix it in Qt.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add Google's Maven repository to build.gradle
   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven

   > ```
   > allprojects {
   >     repositories {
   >         jcenter()
   >         maven {
   >             url 'https://maven.google.com'
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > ```
2. Add dependency to support-v4 library to build.gradle

   > ```
   > dependencies {
   >     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
   >     compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.+" 
   > }
   > ```

Comment: I post this comment in case someone like me will be in the same situation. I come from Android native world and I was looking for the build.gradle file that is located at the "app" level to add the dependency, but it seems that in Qt there is only one build.gradle file, at the project level (at least in my case). In the end I added the dependency directly in the project level build.gradle file and it works just fine ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the dependency to your `build.gradle` file (it's created and added to your project when you create android manifest via Create Templates button).
Something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.+"
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help for me: Could not find any matches for com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.+ as no versions of com.android.support:support-v4 are available.

Comment: how can i update build.gradle? it exists in the build folder but a remark there says: **This file is updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools. Changing them manually might break the compilation!**

Comment: Read carefully. This note is for the gradle.properties file.

Comment: thanks! actually i see that it is for  build.gradle, but on any case, these files are located in the build folder. this folder is created by the qt creator automatically, so i dont want to change anything there. any ideas? thanks!!

Comment: I don't know why your build.gradle is in the build directory. Qt Creator created mine in the source directory in `android` subfolder inside project's dir. Probably it's just copied from source folder and modified while building. You need to locate your file inside source. For this you need to create android manifest first (using Qt Creator). Use "Create Templates" button for this.