# Card Slide Library cannot find symbol variable/class android studio

Tags: android

```
Error:(25, 31) error: package android.support.v4.util does not exist
Error:(26, 31) error: package android.support.v4.view does not exist
Error:(27, 31) error: package android.support.v4.view does not exist
Error:(2189, 17) error: cannot find symbol class SparseArrayCompat
Error:(692, 48) error: cannot find symbol variable MotionEventCompat
Error:(821, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable MotionEventCompat
Error:(858, 27) error: cannot find symbol variable MotionEventCompat
Error:(865, 29) error: cannot find symbol variable MotionEventCompat
Error:(976, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable MotionEventCompat
Error:(977, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable MotionEventCompat
Error:(1976, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable ViewCompat
Error:(2361, 52) error: cannot find symbol variable ViewCompat
Error:(2371, 52) error: cannot find symbol class SparseArrayCompat
Error:(2415, 60) error: cannot find symbol variable ViewCompat
Error:(2425, 60) error: cannot find symbol class SparseArrayCompat
Error:(2464, 26) error: cannot find symbol variable ViewCompat
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:main:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':main:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

**While importing the project to android studio,it shows the error that it didn't find some items from library ,what could be the issue?**

I am waiting for the reply ,please let me know if you find any possible solution to this problem ,I would be very thankful to you

```
**This my build.gradle code**


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    //compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':main')
    compile project(':circularImageView')
    compile project(':com_facebook_android')
    compile project(':main')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/simple-side-drawer2.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-2.2.5.jar')
}
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545576/package-android-support-v4-app-does-not-exist-in-android-studio-0-8

Comment: you can check my buld.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Android Studio, I'm assuming you're using Gradle. Make sure, in your gradle build script (build.gradle) has the appropriate dependencies. For example, when it says "error: package android.support.v4.util does not exist", you're probably missing the support v4 library. You'd need something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
}
```

and so on...

Comment: Its already done ,the issue is the library for card slide is not properly integrated ,i just imported the project form eclipse to android studio