# ItemTouchHelper Class is not known by my Android studio

Tags: android, resolve, itemtouchhelper

i wanted to use the ItemTouchHelper Class, which should be available in the standard installation of android studio (so i wrote in the internet).

Anyhow i get an error message, when i try to use this class.
You can see in picture.
 [Error helper unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zT9V.png)

What can i do, to implement the necessary libary´s respectively the ItemTouchHelper Class.

Pls speak in easy words and describe so detailed as possible, because I am an absolute Android Beginner :)

I would be so glad about an solution!

Best Regards
Fabian

---

Thank you both for your quick reply!

I added the appcompat line in my build.gradel file.

When building gradle i know get following error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zT9V.png)

How can i fix this?

Comment: Check if you have SupportV7 library added as dependencies, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26604814/1105291

Comment: in apps build.gradel file set minSdkVersion.apiLevel   = 9

Comment: Necessary SupportV7 Library dependencies are addes. anyhow Android studio does not know the class... :( 

This are my dependencies:

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'

Answer (score 0):

check this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html

Here ItemTouchHelper class extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration implements RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener

so you should add these dependencies in your app's build.gradel file inside dependency block like this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

Comment: Thank you both for your quick reply!

I added the appcompat line in my build.gradel file.

When building gradle i know get following error message:

Comment: in apps build.gradel file set minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 9